# Ajax - PHP : Extract data from a CSV file without submiting

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, csv

I am a total newbie with AJAX, and i am asking if it's possible to read a CSV file from "file input" and extract data from it and display the data in the same page without sumbiting the form.
here is my codes :

**index.html :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Choose a CSV File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Choose a CSV file :</h1>
    <form method="post" action="csv_to_array.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div>
            <input type="file" name="file" required/>
            <input type="submit" value="Upload CSV Data" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <div>
    <!-- diplaying the data extracted from the csv file -->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**csv_to_array.php :**

```
<?php

if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
  echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
} else {

    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]. "<br>";

    $users = array();

    $labels = array('id', 'name', 'age');

    $fh = fopen ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], 'r');
    fgetcsv($fh);

    if ($fh) {
        while (!feof($fh)) {
            $row = fgetcsv($fh, 500, ';');
            $tempRow = array();
            if (isset($row) && is_array($row) && count($row)>0) {
                foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
                    $tempRow[$labels[$key ]] = $value;
                }
                $users[] = $tempRow;
            }
        }
        fclose($fh);
        $numLines = count($users);
    }

    // I want this to be displayed in index.html :
    echo $numLines;
    echo '<table style="border: 1px solid black;">';
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>ID</td>';
    echo '<td>NAME</td>';
    echo '<td>AGE</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
    for ($x=0; $x<$numLines; $x++) {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>'.$users[$x]['id'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users[$x]['name'].'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$users[$x]['age'].'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';

}

?>
```

Thank you in advance guys!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8244082/1981678

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different way  to do that.
What I recommend is to use a plugin as Blueimp jquery file upload: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

Why is it better to use an already existing Plugin:

1. Security (we are here speaking about uploading a file, there are some security concerns that you have to take in to consideration)
2. File size, format, etc / time to upload
3. Upload progression (progress bar, etc).
4. Community/support

Example of what you can do:

1 - File upload (CSV only, 10 MB max ...)

```
    $('#importData').fileupload({
            dataType: 'json',
            autoUpload: true,
            acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(csv)$/i,
            maxFileSize: 10000000 // 10 MB
            [...]
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
            // You can manage your progress here
    }).on('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
            // You can now call your ajax file that will take care of the CSV (csv_to_array.php)
            (*)
    });
```

2 - Once the upload is done
(represented by the '*' in the code above)

```
    $.ajax({ url: './ajax/csv_to_array.php', 
            data: {file_path:file.name, delete_url: file.deleteUrl},
            type: 'post',
            dataType: "json",
            beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest");},
            success: function(dataCSVFile) {   
                            // Here in Jquery for example you can display your data
            });
```

3 - Be careful at your CSV php process, I recommend you to add a lot of different check to be sure of the format of the file that the user will put. (especially if you plan to save the data in your DB).

Regards,